# Будет ли корректно использовать двоеточие в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

- Что вам еще нужно?
- Ничего(?) у нас уже всё есть.

Можно ли на месте пропуска поставить двоеточие? Или же лучше будет использовать запятую?

Answer (score 1):

***Ничего, у нас уже всё есть.***

В таком предложении ставится запятая, в более сильных знаках (двоеточие или тире) нет необходимости.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП). Хотя отношения между предложениями причинно-следственные, но при отсутствии интонационного предупреждения (понижения голоса, увеличенной паузы) в правилах Розенталя допускается постановка запятой.

Comment: Мне кажется, что при указании на причину можно и без понижения.

Comment: А так нравится?  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150    пункт. 6. Примечание. При отсутствии предупредительной интонации двоеточие в этих случаях не ставится: Сейчас не поедешь, жарко (Ч.). Если совсем нечего делать, то ответьте лучше на такой вопрос:  У нас обобщающие слова с однородным рядом всегда согласуются в падеже? Может быть, есть исключения?

Comment: Предупредительная интонация — это не всегда понижение. Если строго, то надо согласовывать. Но не встречал нигде информации об этом.

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm#з_03  Пункт 9.  Ну и все цитируют Розенталя.  Вот меня и удивляет такая категоричность. не всегда удобно согласовывать. Например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468377/Падежные-окончания-после-двоеточия-корреткны

Comment: Сразу понял, что хотите на этот вопрос ответить. Получается, как и сказал: если строго, то надо — в плане грамматики, а в плане стилистики не всегда так лучше. Ну и не забываем, что 2 элемента — маловато для перечисления.

Comment: Надеюсь, поняли подсказку...

Comment: Мне хотелось найти материалы с комментариями по этой теме, но, вероятно,  со времен Розенталя ничего не изменилось. Отсутствие согласования – это разговорный вариант, к употреблению не рекомендуется.

Comment: Намекал на то, что, раз элемента лишь два, можно, если не лучше, тире поставить. Там нет ограничений. Если нет согласования, то это не перечисление, а пояснение. А первое там не сильно подходит: *основывается на приграничном географическом положении, запасах водных и рекреационных ресурсов*.

Comment: Вообще-то оно должно так подставляться, что-то здесь не то. Можно ли основывать что-то на преимуществах? Не совсем. Основывать можно на фактах (преимущества).