# Падежные окончания после двоеточия корректны?

Tags: согласование, падежи, однородные-члены

*Документ основывается на конкурентных преимуществах региона: **приграничное географическое положение, запасы водных и рекреационных ресурсов.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

*В документе использованы  конкурентные **преимущества** региона: приграничное географическое **положение**, **запасы** водных и рекреационных ресурсов.*

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
По правилу Розенталя обобщающее слово должно быть согласовано в падеже с членами однородного ряда. В данном случае удобнее изменить падеж обобщающего слова,то есть использовать И.п.

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm#з_03](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/67.htm#%D0%B7_03)  Пункт 9.

9. При наличии в предложении обобщающего слова однородные члены **должны согласоваться** с ним в падеже. Положение это иногда нарушается, например: «Фактические данные приводятся в различных газетно-публицистических жанрах: статья, корреспонденция, очерк» (однородные члены следовало поставить в предложном падеже).

Разговорный характер имеет смещенная конструкция типа: Шум, крики, смех – всей этой пестрой гаммой звуков была наполнена ярмарочная площадь (ср. вариант с согласованными однородными членами: Шумом, криками, смехом – всей этой пестрой гаммой звуков...)

Comment: А почему "в предложном падеже", а не "в предложный падеж"?